# Using Cocos 2D-x with Visual Studio 2012 Cross-platform

Tags: android, ios, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x

I am a new to cocos 2D-x. I want to develop applications using cocos 2d-x on cross-platform (typically android, ios and windows 8). I have seen that there is a cocos 2d-x build for windows 8.

My questions are:

1. Can cocos 2d-x be used to develop such a cross-platform app?
2. Can we setup cocos 2d-x with Visual Studio 2012 on windows to make such an application?
3. If yes, any steps are welcome.

Thank you!

Regards,

Gaurav

Comment: no problem with windows8 and android, but cannot for ios. you can develop there for ios, but cannot build and release on ios.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the [cocos2d-x-for-win8](http://cocos2d-x.googlecode.com/files/cocos2d-x-for-win8-0.11.0.zip) zip file and extract it, you should find a guide.chm help file that provides step-by-step instructions that walk you through the installation and use of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you develop using the html platform [Cocos2d-html5](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Download) you can build for multiple platforms ([here is a basic tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32970/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-game-with-cocos2d-javascript-tutorial-getting-started)).

as for you second question you would just create a new project (web site) then code your javascript.

Currently Im having a problem getting VS to notice cocos2d classes.  It was working in Eclipse so idk whats wrong.  Just a heads up if you go this route.